# Converting a list of arrays to list of a single boolean value for each array in tha list

Tags: python, boolean

> `This is a my simple code to find inliers and outliers:

for i in range(len(data)):
if len(data) != 0:
model_robust, inliers = ransac(data,LineModelND,     min_samples= 2,residual_threshold=1, max_trials= 1000)

```
    outliers = inliers == False
    np.append(inliers, 0)

    #computing outliers for each iteration
    outliers = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if inliers[i] == False:
           outliers.append(data[i])
```

I'm trying find numbers of outliers each iteration as a single boolean value which represents a point in the data.

Comment: What does the boolean value represent? Or is it always `True` regardless of the array contents?

Comment: `[True] * len(data)`.

Comment: @superbrain No, that will make them all references to the same list.

Comment: @Barmar You mean the same `True` singleton?

Comment: Sorry, thought you meant `[[True]] * len(data)`. He wants the boolean nested in another list.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not convinced they do. Seems to make even less sense imho.

Comment: So you want `[True, True, True]` or `[array([True]), array([True]), array([True])]`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, the boolean value represent a point where its considered an outlier

Comment: I want [array([True]), array([True]), array([True])]?

Comment: each array in that list should be replaced with its corresponding boolean value (which is True).

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension.

If you want a list of arrays:

```
result = [np.array([True]) for _ in data]
```

If you want a list of booleans:

```
result = [True] * len(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for help and I'm sorry for confusing, it's not always True.

Comment: If it's not always `True`, how to determine what it should be?

Comment: Thank, I'm using ransac algorithm :                                                                            for i in range(len(data)):
    if len(data) != 0:
        model_robust, inliers = ransac(data,  LineModelND, min_samples= 2,
        residual_threshold=1, max_trials= 1000)

        outliers = inliers == False
        np.append(inliers, 0)

        #computing outliers 
        outliers = []
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if inliers[i] == False:
               outliers.append(data[i])

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. Update the question to clarify.

Comment: Okay. I'm a new user of stackflow! I will try to update the question. Thanks.